# Bootstrap 5 carousel indicator for multiple carousels

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to trigger multiple carousel sliders via data-bs-target. I tried with class name instead of ID, but it triggers only one.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
<div id="carouselA" class="carousel slide carouselBoth" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target=".carouselBoth" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target=".carouselBoth" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-bs-target=".carouselBoth" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-6">

<div id="carouselB" class="carousel slide carouselBoth" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I was guessing `data-bs-target=".carouselBoth"` would work but looks like I was wrong or I missed something

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/elyor/6k2p5xes/10/)

Comment: Please reply or accept an answer so others know the question is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap 5 beta docs...

> "Control and indicator elements must have a data-bs-target attribute
> (or href for links) that matches the id of the .carousel element."

So I think only the Collapse component supports [multiple targets](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#multiple-targets). However, you can hook into the `slide.bs.carousel` event of the 1st carousel to trigger slide on the 2nd carousel using javascript...

```
var carouselA = document.getElementById('carouselA')
var carouselB = document.getElementById('carouselB')

carouselA.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    var bsCarouselB = bootstrap.Carousel.getInstance(carouselB)
    bsCarouselB.to(e.to)
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/anDiUXs6d5)