# Does bootstrap allow multiple carousels to be synced via multiple ids in data-target attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please consider the following attempt to sync two bootstrap carousels:

```css
.carousel {
  background: gray;
  
}
.carousel:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightgray;
}

body button {
  background: lightblue !important;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" data-bs-ride="false" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      111
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      222
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      333
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
<div id="carouselExampleControls2" data-bs-ride="false" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      111
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      222
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      333
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>


<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls, #carouselExampleControls2" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls, #carouselExampleControls2" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As you can see only one carsousel is working, but other SO posts suggest that we can use multiple isd in `data-target` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR Seems like still no.

This question has been asked before. The answer from [Zim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65521528/10347145) suggested this was NOT possible back then (Bootstrap `v5.0`).

If you take a look at Bootstrap [`v5.2`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#example) docs, it still says exactly the same:

> Control and indicator elements must have a `data-bs-target` attribute (or `href` for links) that **matches** the `id` of the `.carousel` element.

#### However...

Collapse (not Carousel) component supports [multiple targets](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#multiple-targets), but that is of no help to you since you are interested in Carousel component.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Toggle both elements</button>
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Some placeholder content for the first collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Some placeholder content for the second collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

#### Is there any solution?

[Zim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65521528/10347145) solution using JavaScript (although not as elegant as the one you are asking about).

```js
var carouselA = document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls');
var carouselB = document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls2');

carouselA.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  var bsCarouselB = bootstrap.Carousel.getInstance(carouselB);
  bsCarouselB.to(e.to);
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  background: gray;
}

.carousel:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightgray;
}

body button {
  background: lightblue !important;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      111
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      222
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      333
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="carouselExampleControls2" lass="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      111
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      222
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      333
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
</button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
</button>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

yes bootstrap allow multiple carousels to be synced via multiple ids in data-target attribute, you get examples from codepen also.
you can follow this link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/carousel/

Comment: Hi user Hello22, can you please provide a working example of synced carousel or a link to working codepen? I have followed your link, it doesn't have an example of synced carousels.

Comment: https://codepen.io/angsa/pen/LrezoO

Comment: unfortunately the link in your last comment is for the _owl carousel_ plugin. My question is about bootstrap carousel.